# Neo4j Non-Rest Environment

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have tried running SDN 4, but still can't seem to make it run without its REST service (web service). I wonder if it is possible to make Neo4j run without REST(Web) service? Currently trying to make an app to do simple CRUD to the database like MyBatis.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use it with neo4j in embedded mode?

Comment: @Luanne I was reading this http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html and when I attempt to follow, it seems that newEmbeddedDatabase has been deprecated. I wonder if this is the way to use neo4j with spring without it being a REST server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SDN 4.1 (4.1.1.RELEASE) supports Neo4j running in embedded mode.

You need the embedded driver dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then you'll configure it. Both auto configuration and java configuration modes are supported. The manual contains information about how to do this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_configuring_the_embedded_driver

There's a sample application that uses the embedded driver: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university/tree/4.1-embedded

Comment: Does it still access the database using HTTP port? I'm going to check it out today